# Check if array has same values as other array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am trying to filter my entites by `tags` array, that can look like this:

```
const tags = ["tag1", "tag2"];
```

Every entity has property tags, that can have existing tags, for example:

```
["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"];
```

Or:

```
["tag1", "tag2"];
```

I need to compare if the tags array and the tags array of entity has the same values.
So far I have tried this code, but it returns an entity even if the two arrays dont have the same values (I'm guessing the `includes()` function is to blame).

```
tags.every((tag: any) => doc.tags.includes(tag));
```

Any ideas how can I check if the arrays have the same values?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean same length and same items in the same place ?

Comment: But really, you need to decide which array is the one that has to have all the values (i.e., which gets the `every` and which gets the `includes`.

Comment: @known-as-bmf not necessary in the same place but same values and same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also compare the length as well

```
tags.every((tag: any) => doc.tags.includes(tag)) && tags.length === doc.tags.length;
```

Comment: I thought that there is some more elegant way to deal with this, but the length check works.

Comment: You should check the length first (for short circuiting) and this wont work in a scenario like this: `['a','b','a']` and `['a','b','c']`.

Comment: Only applicable in case of duplicates, in that case first need to remove dups ones then made the comparison